# MvvmCross - RootViewController

Tags: ios, mvvmcross

I am looking at setting up a view/template that I want to be used on every screen apart from the login screen. For example under the navigation bar I want a view with some fields that will be visible on all screens.

I am not quite sure how to do this. I know int he appdelegate there is a rootviewcontroller on the _window property but I set my view controller with the custom fields under the navbar but my views dont' seem to use that view as the default.

Edit: I kind of want a base view controller that sets common buttons / images for every view.

Answer (score 1):

1.Make you own viewControllerContainer (similar to UINavigationController and UITabBarController), use the childViewControllers api to do so. Thus you can do something just like the UINavigationBar, alway visible.

2.Use a window, make a strong reference to it, (static sharedInstance or put it in AppDelegate), then make it visible.

```
self.mywindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 44)];
self.mywindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.mywindow.hidden = NO;
```

Thus whatever you push/pop or presenting VC, it will be always at top.